# Reducing Common Denominator

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have this pie chart which needs to show a break down of the total time spent. I.e. where the time is being spent.

So I have these times in ms:

```
543284944
4128941
31514898
41243891125
```

I add these up to find the total time spent:

```
41822819908
```

So now each one can be represented as a fraction of this time:

```
543284944/41822819908
etc....
```

These numbers are too large for the API I'm using to make sense of (i believe). So now I want to reduce all these numbers.

How would you go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply convert all numbers to seconds and round the result. If it's still too large.. you can convert to minutes or even hours. For example, 543284944ms becomes 151 hours.

The fraction is dimensionless, so it would be equal but way less than the first one.

Comment: I would prefer to keep the precision though...

Comment: Then you can't really get it small.. I think for a pie chart, precision is not really an issue!

Comment: I know what the issue was, I had one task which was `3` days long and the others were hours, this meant that when turned to a fraction they were so small that they were counted as `0`.

Comment: Try to use lograrithms then ..